# The name Display Alert does not exist in the current context?

Tags: xamarin

I don't know why DisplayAlert not works and if I write page.Displayalert it also does not work

using System;

using Xamarin.Forms;

using UIKit;

namespace test.project
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {

```
    partial void UIButton197_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
    {
        if(textBoxName.Text == "" && textBoxpasswd.Text == "")
        {
            await displayAlert("Hello");
        }


    }

    protected ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }
}
```

}

Comment: DisplayAlert is a method on Page, a XF class.  You are trying to call it from a ViewController, which is iOS specific.

Comment: Where should i write it then?

Comment: why are you creating an iOS only page in a XF project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Jason say, is a method on Page but if you really need you can try this :

```cs
await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert ("Hello", "No");
```

Answer (score 0):

displayAlert. This is supposed to be DisplayAlert. And partial void UIButton197_TouchUpInside should be async.